# Search and match using excel headers with duplicated values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As indicated in the example spreadsheet below, I need to identify if a value appears under a specific column header, and there are many repeats of data in the 50 or so columns that this is going to be looking at.  I've tried different things but I can't figure out to make excel search the 4 rows beneath where it finds the data to match.  I also realize in the example the formula should output a yes or no.

Example spreadsheet:

[image: Example Spreadsheet]

Any help would be appreciated.  I would like to do this with formulas if possible.

Comment: You could use `HLOOKUP` or `MATCH`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @jsheeran agreed. Though if recommending match i'd also recommend the obvious inclusion of isna() also

Comment: Thank you guys for your help,  I came up with =IFERROR(HLOOKUP(F1,'Computed Stat Values'!A1:CA10,MATCH(C2,'Computed Stat Values'!B1:B10,0),FALSE),"No")
However that only works if I set the range for the match to the area where I know the header value matches,  if I extend the range for the match to A1:CB10 the result is always "No"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your worksheet image is in error.  Either X and Y should be reversed, or your statement as to what you are looking for.

The following finds out if `Y` is in the column headed by `X`

If so, it will return a positive number; if not, it will return an error value.

`myTable`, `X` and `Y` refer to the obvious.

We use the `INDEX` function with `row` or `column` set to `0` to return an entire row or column, depending.

```
=MATCH(Y,INDEX(myTable,0,MATCH(X,INDEX(myTable,1,0),0)),0)
```

Comment: Yes, I realized that after I posted the picture, I guess the goal is to determine if a value falls under a header, with repeated data in the values

Comment: This worked like a charm,  I should have come here sooner... I've been trying to figure out how to make this work for the better part of a day now.
Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Hah, I just couldn't remember the syntax for any row / column in index and it was driving me crazy. I see the `0` in your answer and now I am kicking myself. Nice answer, and thanks for settling the frustration I had with myself.

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor Yes, it is helpful when writing formulas that might refer to a variable address or table size.

Answer (score 1):

***Edited to fit your correct ranges*** - sheet name needed adding to the first ADDRESS formula

**I have completed the formulas up to row 100, you will need to update to the correct number of rows**

I came up with this solution, though it uses `INDIRECT` which is volatile. There may be a better solution (i will try some INDEX MATCHING for it now too) but for now this will work:

`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C2,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,MATCH(F1,'Computed Stat Values'!A1:CB1,0),1,1,"Computed Stat Values")&":"&ADDRESS(100,MATCH(F1,'Computed Stat Values'!A1:CB1,0),1,1)),0)),"No","Yes")`

Essentially I am using `ADDRESS` and `INDIRECT` to build the array range for the column we want to match in based on the title row match.

`ADDRESS(2` and `ADDRESS(4` are the start row and end row of match data, please update to cover sufficient rows.

**EDIT** - Found a much neater way on SO's sister site SuperUser: [Link here.](https://superuser.com/a/880354)

`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C2,OFFSET('Computed Stat Values'!A1:A100,0,MATCH(F1,'Computed Stat Values'!A1:CB1,0)-1),0)),"No","Yes")`

Offset's the column number by the match in the title row. Genius!

Comment: Thank you for helping, I've been trying to massage these into my actual workbook... which is surprisingly not about pies and cakes... The first one always returned an error, which I think is because the first Match needs to search a separate worksheet 
`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C2,INDIRECT("'Computed Stat Values'!"&ADDRESS(2,MATCH(F1,'Computed Stat Values'!A1:CB1,0))&":'Computed Stat Values'!"&ADDRESS(4,MATCH(F1,'Computed Stat Values'!A1:CB1,0))),0)),"No","Yes")`
and that appeared to create the correct reference when I messed with the commands independently, but I it would always error.

Comment: The second one is always returning a value of 2, no matter if there is a match or not or even if the data is on the worksheet, out of curiosity,  should the range directly following offset be on the second worksheet, or does it matter?

Comment: @MichaelElse Edit made to include your ranges. I completed this to row 100, you will need to update to reflect the true size of your data.

Comment: So the issue was the rows,  I didn't realize I needed to change as I thought the match formulas were just searching the top row for a match and then getting the column value to assemble the range for the first match formula.

Comment: ... wow I just realized the problem was that I was adding the sheet name twice in the thing I did... I feel dumb.

Comment: Haha, no problem. Sorry for not making it whole columns too but I use so many array formulas now that it's drilled into me to define exact ranges ^^